# Prestashop 1.7: Cannot get value of custom field from Order object on order-detail.tpl file

Tags: object, prestashop-1.7

I want to access the custom field added to the ps_orders table on `order-details.tpl`.

I have overridden Order file like below.

```
    class Order extends OrderCore
    {
      /**
         * @var int Round type method used for this order
         */
        public $total_seat_price;
    
        public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null)
        {
          parent::__construct($id, $id_lang);

          self::$definition['fields']['total_seat_price'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT);
        parent::__construct($id, $id_lang);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Now. I want to show this price on the order details page. When I print the `{$order.details}` I can see the field in the object. But when I try to access `{$order.details.total_seat_price}`. It gives me blank value. Though I can access other fields from the object. Can anyone please guide me?

[image]

Comment: Can you use `{debug}` in your smarty.tpl it will show you all available variables and values. Is it also blank there?

Comment: @Crezzur Yes I am getting the value in object. I added I Image